# Return a array of object with sprecific keys

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i have a array of objects which define below

```
const jsObjects = [
{
    "ID": 5,
    "Question": "How long have you been using old service?",
    "QuestionID": 1,
    "Type": "Radio",
    "answers":  [
       {
        "SurveyAnswer": "0-1year",
        "UniqueID": 6,
        
      },
       {
        "SurveyAnswer": "1-2years",
        "UniqueID": 7,
        "isCheck": true,
      },
       {
        "SurveyAnswer": "3-5years",
        "UniqueID": 8,
      },
    ],
  },
  
  {
    "ID": 6,
    "Question": "How long have you been using new service?",
    "QuestionID": 2,
    "Type": "Radio",
    "answers":  [
       {
        "SurveyAnswer": "0-1year",
        "UniqueID": 6,
        
      },
       {
        "SurveyAnswer": "1-2years",
        "UniqueID": 7,
        "isCheck": true,
      },
       {
        "SurveyAnswer": "3-5years",
        "UniqueID": 8,
      },
    ],
  },
]
```

What I'm trying to do here is  to return a new array which only have `isChecked: true` in the `answers` array.

So the output will be

```
const jsObjects = [
{
    "ID": 5,
    "Question": "How long have you been using old service?",
    "QuestionID": 1,
    "Type": "Radio",
    "answers":  [
       {
        "SurveyAnswer": "1-2years",
        "UniqueID": 7,
        "isCheck": true,
      }
    ],
  },
  
  {
    "ID": 6,
    "Question": "How long have you been using new service?",
    "QuestionID": 2,
    "Type": "Radio",
    "answers":  [
       {
        "SurveyAnswer": "1-2years",
        "UniqueID": 7,
        "isCheck": true,
      }
    ],
  },
]
```

I tried filter method on JSObjects but getting undefined

```
let result = jsObjects.answers.filter(obj => {
  return obj.isCheck === true
})
```

What i'm doing wrong here ?

Thanks in Advance ......

Comment: Sorry for the Typo. Its stil Undefined

Comment: link to fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/fc4yru6n/

Comment: There is no `jsObjects.answers`. You need to use `filter` on each object inside the array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have 2 nested arrays, you can generate a new array using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and then use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the desired elements in the nested array like this:

```js
const result = jsObjects.map(({ answers, ...rest }) => ({ 
  ...rest,
  answers: answers.filter(answer => answer.isCheck === true)
}));
```

Here's the full example:

```js
const jsObjects = [
{
    "ID": 5,
    "Question": "How long have you been using old service?",
    "QuestionID": 1,
    "Type": "Radio",
    "answers":  [
       {
        "SurveyAnswer": "0-1year",
        "UniqueID": 6,
        
      },
       {
        "SurveyAnswer": "1-2years",
        "UniqueID": 7,
        "isCheck": true,
      },
       {
        "SurveyAnswer": "3-5years",
        "UniqueID": 8,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    "ID": 6,
    "Question": "How long have you been using new service?",
    "QuestionID": 2,
    "Type": "Radio",
    "answers":  [
       {
        "SurveyAnswer": "0-1year",
        "UniqueID": 6,
        
      },
       {
        "SurveyAnswer": "1-2years",
        "UniqueID": 7,
        "isCheck": true,
      },
       {
        "SurveyAnswer": "3-5years",
        "UniqueID": 8,
      },
    ],
  },
]

const result = jsObjects.map(({ answers, ...rest }) => ({ 
  ...rest,
  answers: answers.filter(answer => answer.isCheck === true)
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You can also delete === true to make it easier :v

Comment: @tranminhquang I leave it like this on purpose in case OP specifically wants it has to be exact `true`, but you are right, in most of the cases it's not nessesary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the map and filter to return the new array with require values. Below is the working snippet with your expected output

```js
const jsObjects = [{
    "ID": 5,
    "Question": "How long have you been using old service?",
    "QuestionID": 1,
    "Type": "Radio",
    "answers": [{
        "SurveyAnswer": "0-1year",
        "UniqueID": 6,

      },
      {
        "SurveyAnswer": "1-2years",
        "UniqueID": 7,
        "isCheck": true,
      },
      {
        "SurveyAnswer": "3-5years",
        "UniqueID": 8,
      },
    ],
  },

  {
    "ID": 6,
    "Question": "How long have you been using new service?",
    "QuestionID": 2,
    "Type": "Radio",
    "answers": [{
        "SurveyAnswer": "0-1year",
        "UniqueID": 6,

      },
      {
        "SurveyAnswer": "1-2years",
        "UniqueID": 7,
        "isCheck": true,
      },
      {
        "SurveyAnswer": "3-5years",
        "UniqueID": 8,
      },
    ],
  },
]
const data = jsObjects.map(data => {
  return {
    ID: data.ID,
    Question: data.Question,
    QuestionID: data.QuestionID,
    Type: data.Type,
    answers: data.answers.filter(data => data.isCheck)
  }
});
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop against every "Outer" jsObject and change the answers array inside it. So it could be something like:

```
jsObjects.map(jsObj => {
    jsObj.answers = jsObj.answers.filter(ans => ans.isCheck)
    return jsObj
})
```

**EDIT:**
this **will mutate** the original object. So if you don't need to do that, you might destructure the object in the `map` callback or create another reference for the object first using something like `const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsObjects));`

Comment: Won't this change the original `jsObjects` contents?

Comment: Right, thanks @TheVee, I edited the answer and wanted to mention you in it but couldn't